# Sublime Text 3 Color Scheme for Tags

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I been using [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) on Mac OSX since it has been released. Currently using Build 3059. But I have yet to figure out a way to change the Color Scheme for Tags.

- It shows all HTML tags (ie. `<td>`, `<tr>`) as blue.
- It shows everything that is in quotes in green (ie. `<xsl:template match="counter">`) where `"counter"` would be in green.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I know that I can change the "Color Scheme" to something else so that the colors are different, but can the "Color Scheme" be manually edited so that not everything is blue and green.

**For Example:** `<td>` would be brown while `<tr>` would be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors applied are based on scopes. Scopes are applied based on regular expressions in the tmLanguage files. To get coloring as fine grained as you want, you would need to edit the tmLanguage file to uniquely identify specific tags and the tmTheme file so the appropriate color is assigned to the new scopes you define in the tmLanguage file.

Comment: Where would I find "tmLanguage" file? I looked under Show Package Contents, and also did a search, found nothing.

Comment: I'd recommend using https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer. If you make modifications to the tmLanguage file, it will save it in the appropriate location to override the built in file. By doing this, you will always be able to "revert".  Won't go into to much detail, but ST3 runs plugins from `*.sublime-package` files, rather than extracting them. So looking for them through "normal" means (such as finder) is more involved than it was in ST2. If you would like a more detailed explanation, let me know.